# Differences in the letter "z" in Times New Roman packages

Tags: fonts, letters, times

I am compiling a document in tex using a Times New Roman math font. There are numerous packages one can install to do the job, and all have their pros and cons. One thing that is common to all the Times packages I have seen so far is the characteristic "flick" on the letter z (see below), which I have never been a fan of. Is there a package out there that produces the letter z in the style on the left, or can someone suggest an amendment to mathptmx or any other good Times packages that changes the style of this letter alone?

[image]

Comment: the stix fonts were based on times (though not entirely identical).  one "adjustment" was removal of the swash tail on the "z" as it interferes with subscripts.  but stix 2.0 is entirely opentype, so if you're using pdflatex there's not good support for it.  (xits was based on stix 1.0, so might be worth looknig at also.)

Comment: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/stix/ according to this, stix still as the tail on the "z", and xits has a slightly more bizarre alteration where the tail is still present, but seemingly cut off.

Comment: Note the Word version is b not italic, but slanted. Lowercase variables in usual mathematics are italic.

Comment: Is there an option for making variables slanted in tex?

Comment: i'm sure that the tail was straightened for the math font; it may have been "restored" for italic text.  i will check.

Comment: when you ask about "variables" do you mean one-letter "names" or multi-letter?  single letters in tex math are *always* italic unless explicitly specified otherwise.